# How to convert from const char* to unsigned int c++

Tags: c++

I am new in c++ programming and I have been trying to convert from const char* to unsigned int with no luck.
I have a:

```
const char* charVar;
```

and i need to convert it to:

```
unsigned int uintVar;
```

How can it be done in C++?

Thanks

Comment: -1 it's not clear what you mean with *convert* here. What did you try?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

const char* value = "1234567";
stringstream strValue;
strValue << value;

unsigned int intValue;
strValue >> intValue;

cout << value << endl;
cout << intValue << endl;
```

Output:

> 1234567
>
> 1234567

Comment: great example. I changed unsigned int to just int, and it seems to work with negative numbers now too.

Comment: That answer does not involve casting, and it bring in a bunch of complicated features that are not necessarily needed for C++. Ideally, you'd figure out how to not use the stl or templates at all. Pulling these features in substantially increases compile time. When I rid my small xml parser of most references to the stl it took compile times from 30 seconds to less than a second. This is why big projects end up taking an hour to compile, unless you have a 64 core cpu at home.

Answer (score 27):

What do you mean by convert?

If you are talking about reading an integer from the text, then you have several options.

Boost lexical cast: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm

String stream:

```
const char* x = "10";
int y;
stringstream s(x);
s >> y;
```

Or good old C functions `atoi()` and `strtol()`

Comment: ... though I am now tempted to remove it for CRT pandering :-)

Answer (score 22):

If you really want to convert a pointer to a constant character into an unsigned int then you should use in c++:

```
const char* p;
unsigned int i = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int>( p );
```

This converts the address to which the pointer points to into an unsigned integer.

If you want to convert the content to which the pointer points to into an unsigned int you should use:

```
const char* p;
unsigned int i = static_cast<unsigned int>( *p );
```

If you want to get an integer from a string, and hence interpret the const char* as a pointer to a const char array, you can use one of the solutions mentioned above.

Answer (score 8):

The C way:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    const char *charVar = "16";
    unsigned int uintVar = 0;

    uintVar = atoi(charVar);

    return 0;
}
```

The C++ way:

```
#include <sstream>
int main() {
    istringstream myStream("16");
    unsigned int uintVar = 0;

    myStream >> uintVar;

    return 0;
}
```

Notice that in neither case did I check the return code of the conversion to make sure it actually worked.

Answer (score 6):

In C this can be done using `atoi` which is also available to C++ via `cstdlib`.

Comment: What does `atoi("blah")` return? And how is that different from `atoi(0)`?

Comment: Just note that `atoi()` is probably the worst choice from all the options available.

Comment: There is a reason it is called the **C** Runtime Library.

Comment: It depends on your use case whether `atoi` is bad. First of all it is by far the shortest of all solutions. On the other hand it does no error checking. So it really is only a quick and dirty way I have often found to be useful.

Comment: I have yet to find a use case where I wouldn't mind whether I got wrong data without any real indication.

Answer (score 3):

I usually use this generic function to convert a string into "anything":

```
  #include <sstream>
  // Convert string values into type T results.
  // Returns false in case the conversion fails.
  template <typename T>
  bool getValueFromString( const std::string & value, T & result )
  {
    std::istringstream iss( value );
    return !( iss >> result ).fail();
  }
```

just use it as in:

```
int main()
{
  const char * a_string = "44";
  unsigned int an_int;
  bool         success;

  // convert from const char * into unsigned int
  success = getValueFromString( a_string, an_int );


  // or any other generic convertion
  double       a;
  int          b;
  float        c;
  // conver to into double
  success = getValueFromString( "45", a );

  // conve rto into int
  success = getValueFromString( "46", b );

  // conver to into float
  success = getValueFromString( "47.8", c );
}
```

Comment: "Anything"? It will not work for negative integers. `success` will be equal to 0 even if you call `getValueFromString("-123", an_int)` and you'll get garbage value in `an_int`.

Comment: @glihm: `an_int` was declared as `unsigned int` and therefore you cannot assign a negative number to it. and what was stored in `an_int` was not "garbage" but the 2's complement representation of `-123`.

Comment: Oh great @Sdra, thanks to clarify it! I had tried and though that values were garbage. :)

Answer (score 2):

[`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/) function will convert const char* to int, which can be implicitly converted to unsigned. This won't work for large integers that don't fit in int.

A more C++-ish way is to use strings and streams

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   std::string strVar;
   unsigned uintVar;
   std::istringstream in(strVar);
   in >> uintVar;
}
```

An easier but nonstandard way would be to use boost's [lexical cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm).

HTH

Comment: The problem with answers like this is they need to learn the C way for performance purposes. They have to learn how stringstream works under the hood, and build their own before using the default. At least, how I think C++ should be taught is you teach C, and have them build a rudimentary C++ for the class.

Comment: @ZeroPhase: As someone  who has been teaching C++ for about 10 years, I have quite the opposite opinion. In my opinion attempting to learn C++ "bottom up" is a no go.

Answer (score 2):

So I know this is old but thought I would provide a more efficient way of doing this that will give you some flexibility on what you want as a base is.

```
#include<iostream>

unsigned long cstring_to_ul(const char* str, char** end = nullptr, int base = 10)
{
    errno = 0; // Used to see if there was success or failure

    auto ul = strtoul(str, end, base);

    if(errno != ERANGE)
    {
       return ul;
    }

    return ULONG_MAX;
}
```

What this will do is create a wrapper around the method strtoul(const char* nptr, char** endptr, int base) method from C. For more information on this function you can read the description from the man page here https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoul

Upon failure you will have errno = ERANGE, which will allow you to do a check after calling this function along with the value being ULONG_MAX.

An example of using this can be as follows:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned long ul = cstring_to_ul("3284201");

    if(errno == ERANGE && ul == ULONG_MAX)
    {
        std::cout << "Input out of range of unsigned long.\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    std::cout << "Output: " << ul << "\n";
 }
```

This will give the output

> Output: 3284201

Answer (score 2):

Try in this way

```
#include<iostream>
#include <typeinfo>             //includes typeid

using namespace std;

int main(){

char a  = '3';
int k = 3;

const char* ptr = &a;

cout << typeid(*ptr).name() << endl;                    //prints the data type c = char
cout << typeid(*ptr-'0').name() << endl;                //prints the data type i = integer

cout << *ptr-'0' << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/late-answers/26300915)

Answer (score 1):

Without more information there is no way to properly answer this question. What are you trying to convert exactly? If charVar is an ascii representation of the string, then you can do like others have suggested and use stringstreams, atoi, sscanf, etc.

If you want the actual value pointed to by charVar, then instead you'd want something like:

```
intValue = (unsigned int)(*charVal);
```

Or if charVal is the pointer to the first byte of an unsigned integer then:

```
intValue = *((unsigned int*)(charVal));
```

Comment: Doesn't that break strict aliasing rule?

Comment: Let_Me_Be: I had been under the impression that it was valid to cast to or from char*. I looked into it and in fact it seems like it may only be valid to cast to char*, but not from char*. I see that idiom quite a lot though, so I need to do some additional research.

Answer (score 1):

```
const char* charVar = "12345";
unsigned int uintVar;
try {
  uintVar = std::stoi( std::string(charVar) );
}
catch(const std::invalid_argument& e) {
  std::cout << "Invalid Arg: " << e.what() << endl;
}
catch(const std::out_of_range& e) {
  std::cout << "Out of range: " << e.what() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `strtoul` or `_tcstoul` to get unsigned long value from `const char*` and then cast the value to unsigned int.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k9xb7x1(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
const char* charVar = "1864056953";
unsigned int uintVar = 0;

for (const char* it = charVar; *it != 0; *it++){

    if ((*it < 48) || (*it > 57)) break;            // see ASCII table

    uintVar *= 10;                                  // overflow may occur
    uintVar += *it - 48;                            // 
}

std::cout << uintVar << std::endl;
std::cout << charVar << std::endl;
```

Comment: If you use `'0'` instead of `48` and `'9'` instead of `57` you won't depend on ASCII.

Comment: Also, in `*it++` the `*` has no effect. `it++` is sufficient (I would actually use `++it`). Finally, the `uintVar < 0` comparison makes no sense because your data type is `unsigned`.

Comment: My answer is trying to show some conceptual points.
Otherwise, 2 lines solutions would be best option here.

Comment: it++ is not sufficient. (Thanks for unsigned int)

Comment: `*it++` makes no sense. You increment the pointer and then you dereference it, but you don't do anything with the value you get.